# IEnumerable collections get set to 0 or null when called from inside a Thread if I use

Tags: c#, multithreading, ienumerable, zero, isnullorempty

I have a class that is running a process in a thread and whenever I try to use an IEnumerable method on a List property on the class, it zeros out the list or makes it null.  My other class properties retain their values.  I have tried other types of IEnumerable derived classes including ConcurrentQueue and ConcurrentStack, and all of the derived classes seem to have the same issue. I have tried researching this for days to no avail.  Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

```
namespace ThreadProblem
{
public class TestMyClass
{

    public void StartTest()
    {
        MyClass testX = new MyClass(new List<BuildParam>() { BuildParam.value1, BuildParam.value2, BuildParam.value3 },"These are great comments");
        testX.TestThread();

        Console.WriteLine("testX has {0} members in the Build Parameters list",testX.BuildParameters.Count());
    }


}

public class MyClass
{
    public List<BuildParam> BuildParameters { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }


    public MyClass(List<BuildParam> parameters, string comments)
    {
        BuildParameters = parameters;
        Comments = comments;
    }

    public void TestThread()
    {
        Thread testThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(executeProcess));
        testThread.Start();

        Thread testThread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(executeProcess2));
        testThread2.Start();
    }

    void executeProcess()
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Calling process containing IEnumerable extension method - Parameter count {0}", BuildParameters.Count());
            Console.WriteLine("Calling process containing IEnumerable extension method - Comments: {0}", Comments);

            //here is what seems to cause the issue....
            string paramsList = String.Format("Calling process containing IEnumerable extension method - These parameters will be used: {0}", String.Join(", ", BuildParameters.Select(t => t.ToString())));

            foreach (var item in BuildParameters)
            {
                //do something
                Console.WriteLine("Calling process containing IEnumerable extension method - Howdy, I am {0}", item.ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Calling process containing IEnumerable extension method - Comments Again: {0}", Comments);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }


    void executeProcess2()
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Calling process not containing IEnumerable extension method - Comments: {0}", Comments);
            foreach (var item in BuildParameters)
            {
                //do something
                Console.WriteLine("Calling process not containing IEnumerable extension method - Hi, I am {0}", item.ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Calling process not containing IEnumerable extension method - Comments again: {0}", Comments);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }

}    

public enum BuildParam
{
    value1,
    value2,
    value3
}
}
```

This produces output similar to this:

```
Calling process not containing IEnumerable extension method - Comments: These are great comments
testX has 3 members in the Build Parameters list
Calling process not containing IEnumerable extension method - Hi, I am value1
Calling process not containing IEnumerable extension method - Hi, I am value2
Calling process not containing IEnumerable extension method - Hi, I am value3
Calling process not containing IEnumerable extension method - Comments again: These are great comments
Calling process containing IEnumerable extension method - Parameter count 3
Calling process containing IEnumerable extension method - Comments: These are great commentscomments
```

Comment: Are you sure there's no exception being thrown? put a breakpoint on your `throw ex`.

Comment: There is a ThreadAbortException, but I am not clear on how this would cause the count for the BuildParameters property value to go from 3 to 0 in the middle of executing the executeProcess() proc.  it has the correct count in line 1 of the proc and in the for loop it is 0...  The exception won't get raised until after the for loop is entered

Comment: If I add a `Console.ReadLine()` to the end of the `StartTest` method, the program runs to completion and produces the expected output. I am unable to make your code fail as you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this line is throwing an exception:

```
//here is what seems to cause the issue....
string paramsList = String.Format("Calling process containing IEnumerable extension method - These parameters will be used: {0}", String.Join(", ", BuildParameters.Select(t => t.ToString())));
```

Wrap that in a try/catch and output the exception information:

```
string paramsList;
try
{
    string parms = string.Join(", ",  BuildParameters.Select(t => t.ToString())));
    paramsList = String.Format(
        "Calling process containing IEnumerable extension method - These parameters will be used: {0}",
        parms);
    Console.WriteLine(paramsList);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception!");
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

Or you could wrap your entire thread proc in that. Be careful, though. You shouldn't blindly catch all exceptions like this in production code. It's nice for debugging, but don't leave it in the production code.

Comment: Yes there is an exception being thrown... it is a ThreadAbortException but this doesn't occur until after I try to access the property in my for loop. I guess I don't understand how the exception forces the property, BuildParameters, to 0.

Comment: Jim: I tried your suggestion... the String .Format line doesn't raise an exception.  It only pops when I try to access the property in the foreach statement.

Comment: @ChristopherJordan: Then move the `catch` so that it encompasses the loop, too. We need to see what the exception is. Also, could it be that you're getting the `ThreadAbortException` because your program is exiting and killing the thread prematurely? What happens if you put a `Thread.Sleep(5000)` in your `StartTest` method, so it gives the threads time to complete their work?

Comment: I think you hit on the problem... The thread was being killed prematurely if I sleep the thread for 10 seconds it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your `executeProcess` thread aborts with an exception. Just rethrowing it is not enough. Try adding this, for example in your main method:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += delegate(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: Here, you can access the exception as a parameter of e.
    // So you can debug it, log it, output it, store it in a file, whatever.
}
```

Comment: Jan: Yes, I apologize for not including that information.  My misunderstanding comes from not knowing what is causing the property to go from a count of 3 to a count of 0.  How will error handling fix this? I guess I am not getting that part.

Comment: It doesn't. Your code never reaches the `foreach` because the exception makes the thread terminate before that.

Comment: Any idea on what is causing it to abort?  The exception isn't raised until teh for loop is entered. What do you think is causing the thread to abort when the Extension method is called?  Error handling is great, but I don't see how that is going to fix my underlying issue of needing that code executed...

Comment: Any exception in any thread will cause said thread to abort. So the line in which the exception occurs is the last line that will be executed. So if the line `string paramsList = String.Format("Calling process containing IEnumerable extension method - These parameters will be used: {0}", String.Join(", ", BuildParameters.Select(t => t.ToString())));` raises an exception, anything after that will not be executed. So your property does not go from 3 to 0, its just the thread aborting.

Comment: In order to find out what is wrong with that line, we would have to know what the exception actually is.

Comment: I see.  I wrapped the offending line of code with a try catch and nothing got triggered.  code line looks like this now: try
                {
                    string paramsList = String.Format("Calling process containing IEnumerable extension method - These parameters will be used: {0}", String.Join(", ", BuildParameters.Select(t => t.ToString())));
                }
                catch (Exception ex1)
                {
                    throw ex1;
                }

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint at `throw ex1;`? Does that get triggered?

Comment: The message jus says : ExceptionState = Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.

Comment: Jan I put a breakpoint at throw ex1; but it did not trigger. Only my original catch catches any errors...

Comment: I am very sorry, but consider me stumped, then.

Comment: I appreciate your attempt. If you run it through the debugger you can see what I am talking about...